# reload webpage certain timing even no one use it

Tags: javascript, php, web, reload

I want create a website certain time of the day(e.g. 9pm) will auto reload the webpage . 
The main point to reload the webpage is to insert some data into database at certain time even no one viewing at the webpage.

My Idea:
Database A : Everytime reach 12am , they will update all the data to 0.
Database B : Want to insert data from database A to track the old data:

```
INSERT INTO `report`(`updated_date`, `name`, `occupied`) VALUES ('$time','S','$arrayS[$i]')
```

Due to Database_A 12am will always auto update all the data to 0 , so I need to store the data to Database B. So the User will be able to view the old data.

Current Date is base on Database A and Previous data base on DatabaseB:

### (image example :) http://gyazo.com/54e93de27690291a80a3be0d07868b66

I have research afew method and tried out :

1.This method only work when I was viewing the web.However after I close ,no action will be taken.

```
    $page = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];

$now = time();
$today = strtotime('12:12');
$tomorrow = strtotime('tomorrow 12:12');
if (($today - $now) > 0) {
    $refreshTime = $today - $now;
} else {
    $refreshTime = $tomorrow - $now;
}

header("Refresh: $refreshTime; url=$page");
```

Comment: Schedule a task on your operating system to execute `php script.php` every 12 hours (cron job).

Comment: why not use a cron job? That's what cron is for.

Comment: What is your server config? you can use cron to do your job.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a `cron` if on a linux based environment or `Windows Scheduler` if you're on a Windows based environment.